# Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch

Tags: login, debian-squeeze

Once Debian booted up and I was able to login (put username and password), but now the cursor shows a watch which means it's waiting for something. I switched to a virtual terminal with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and ran `tail /var/log/xorg.0.log` which said that it is suspending AIGLX clients for virtual terminal switch.

How can I resolve this problem?

I am running Debian Squeeze.

Comment: Likely a false lead.  Try taking a look in `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: Resolve it long time back..and forgot to update it here.This is the solution:http://unixbhaskar.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/how-to-get-over-frozen-debian-squeeze-login-screen/